# How can I easily convert all ntext fields to nvarchar(max) in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would love to be able to write a SQL query, without enumerating the columns, which will return me all the columns, and any ntext column converted to varchar(max).  I was wondering if there is a clever way to do this.

This would be great because then I could do the comparison based operators such as UNION, EXCEPT etc. on such queries.  The netxt column is not comparable so it fails when using those operators.

**My current idea:**

Create a function to build the query as dynamic sql.  Something similar to this: http://lotsacode.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/sql-server-ntext-cannot-be-selected-as-distinct/

Is there a better way?

Thanks for your input!

Comment: This worked for me: .http://www.bartread.com/2014/09/17/convert-all-ntext-columns-to-nvarcharmax-sql-server/.  I modded the `INSERT` part of the script to `WHERE   o.type = 'U' AND c.system_type_id IN (99,35);`

Answer (score 7):

`NTEXT` will be removed from future versions of SQl-Server anyway ([along with Image and text](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)), so why not just bite the bullet and change your columns to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`? It may be costly once, but it will probably be worth it:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.T ALTER COLUMN NTextColumn NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL; -- OR NOT NULL
```

You can generate and execute the script for an entire database using this:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
    (   SELECT  'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id)) + '.' + 
                                QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(object_id)) + 
                                ' ALTER COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(Name) + 
                                ' NVARCHAR(MAX) ' + 
                                CASE WHEN is_nullable = 0 THEN 'NOT' ELSE '' END + 
                                ' NULL;' + CHAR(13) + 'GO' + CHAR(13)
        FROM    sys.columns
        WHERE   system_type_id = 99 --NTEXT
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)');

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Good point.  Unfortunately I'm not high enough on the totem-pole to make that move :)

Comment: Then tell whoever is high enough on the Totem-pole to make the change, presumably if they have reached such lofty heights they will realise yours is a good suggestion?

Comment: Any other solution is merely sweeping the issue under the carpet.

Comment: Fantastic script to just "make the change", +1

Comment: it should be is_nullable= 0 then 'NOT'

Answer (score 4):

I used this cursor (and here, there's no set-based alternative, I'm afraid) to do just that:

```
DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD 
FOR
    SELECT 
        t.Name,
        c.name,
        c.is_nullable, 
        typ.user_type_id
    FROM 
        sys.columns c 
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.types typ ON c.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id
    WHERE   
        typ.name IN ('text', 'ntext')    -- user_type_id: text = 35, ntext = 99 

DECLARE @TableName sysname, @ColumnName sysname, @IsNullable BIT, @TypeID INT

OPEN TableCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName, @ColumnName, @IsNullable, @TypeID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Stmt NVARCHAR(999)

    SET @Stmt = 'ALTER TABLE dbo.[' + @TableName + '] ALTER COLUMN [' + @ColumnName + '] ' + 
              CASE @TypeID 
                WHEN 35 THEN ' VARCHAR(MAX) '
                WHEN 99 THEN ' NVARCHAR(MAX) '
              END  + 
                CASE WHEN @IsNullable = 1 THEN 'NULL' ELSE 'NOT NULL' END

    PRINT @Stmt
    EXEC (@Stmt)

    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName, @ColumnName, @IsNullable, @TypeID
END

CLOSE TableCursor
DEALLOCATE TableCursor
```

I simplified my code a bit by assuming that all my tables are in the `dbo` schema - if that's not the case for you, you'd have to include the schema from the `sys.schema` catalog view, too.

Running this code will turn all `text` into `varchar(max)` and all `ntext` into `nvarchar(max)` once and for all, and all your issues with `text/ntext` are gone forever!  :-)

Comment: Don't forget to update the text field to avoid a huge performance hit. [See here.](http://geekswithblogs.net/johnsPerfBlog/archive/2008/04/16/ntext-vs-nvarcharmax-in-sql-2005.aspx) I just inserted these lines after the table was altered: `SET @Stmt = 'UPDATE dbo.[' + @TableName + '] SET [' + @ColumnName + '] = [' + @ColumnName + ']'

    PRINT @Stmt
    EXEC (@Stmt)`

Comment: @cjbarth: ah, interesting post you're linking to - thanks for the heads-up !

Answer (score 1):

Here is my modified version of GarethD's answer above. Had issues with SQL not finding some tables, so I used sys.tables joined with sys.columns. Also, the is_nullable line was incorrect (if the field is not nullable, then you set it to NOT NULL).

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ' ';

SELECT  @SQL = @SQL + ' ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(sys.columns.object_id)) + '.' + 
                        QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(sys.columns.object_id)) + 
                        ' ALTER COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(sys.columns.Name) + 
                        ' NVARCHAR(MAX) ' + 
                        CASE WHEN is_nullable = 0 THEN 'NOT NULL' ELSE '' END 

FROM    sys.Tables
inner join sys.columns on sys.tables.object_id = sys.columns.object_id
WHERE   sys.columns.system_type_id = 99 ; --NTEXT 

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
GO
```